# How to cycle through different colours and assign them to already drawn objects?

Tags: python

I've been given the task to draw a patchwork pattern using Python. I need to get a width and height from the user, both must be greater than 3 but less than 10, and 4 colours, that cannot be the same. I have written the code for that fine. But i need to draw 2 different types of patterns. One pattern is all along the edges, only 1 patch deep, and the second pattern fills in the centre squares. Now, the code i've used to draw this is repeating the first patch along the top, the bottom, and then each side, and then repeating the second pattern throughout the middle. But now i have to assign each different individual patch a colour, cycling through the given colours, so that it starts with the first, cycles through them all, and starts with the first again.

My question is, i have no idea how to cycle through the colours, because the order will be different line by line. Is there a good efficient way of doing it with what i've written so far, ie. drawing an individual patch and repeating it over lines, and if so what is the best way?

```
from graphics import *

def main():
    width, height = getDimensions()
    colour1, colour2, colour3, colour4 = getColours()
    win = drawGraphWin(width, height)
    drawPattern(win, width, height, colour1, colour2, colour3, colour4)

def getDimensions():
    width = input("How many patches, between 4 and 9, would you like \
                    horizontally? :")
    while True:
        try:
            width = int(width)
            break
        except ValueError:
            width = input("How many patches, between 4 and 9, would you like \
                            horizontally? :")
    while width < 4 or width > 9:
        width = eval(input("How many patches, between 4 and 9, would you like \
                            horizontally? :"))
    height = input("How many patches, between 4 and 9, would you like \
                    vertically? :")
    while True:
        try:
            height = int(height)
            break
        except ValueError:
            height = input("How many patches, between 4 and 9, would you like \
                            vertically? :")
    while height < 4 or height > 9:
        height = eval(input("How many patches, between 4 and 9, would you like \
                            vertically? :"))
    return width, height

def getColours():
    colour1 = input("Please enter a colour \
                    (red, green, blue, yellow, magenta, orange, cyan): ")
    while valid1(colour1) == False:
        colour1 = input("Please enter a colour \
                        (red, green, blue, yellow, magenta, orange, cyan): ")
    colour2 = input("Please enter a second colour \
                    (red, green, blue, yellow, magenta, orange, cyan): ")
    while valid2(colour1, colour2) == False:
        colour2 = input("Please enter a second colour \
                        (red, green, blue, yellow, magenta, orange, cyan): ")
    colour3 = input("Please enter third a colour \
                        (red, green, blue, yellow, magenta, orange, cyan): ")
    while valid3(colour1, colour2, colour3) == False:
        colour3 = input("Please enter third a colour \
                        (red, green, blue, yellow, magenta, orange, cyan): ")
    colour4 = input("Please enter a fourth colour \
                    (red, green, blue, yellow, magenta, orange, cyan): ")
    while valid4(colour1, colour2, colour3, colour4) == False:
        colour4 = input("Please enter a fourth colour \
                        (red, green, blue, yellow, magenta, orange, cyan): ")
    return colour1, colour2, colour3, colour4

def valid1(colour1):
    if any( [colour1 == "red", colour1 == "green", colour1 == "blue", \
             colour1 == "yellow", colour1 == "magenta", colour1 == "orange", \
             colour1 == "cyan"]):
        return True
    else:
        return False

def valid2(colour1, colour2):
    if any( [colour2 == "red", colour2 == "green", colour2 == "blue", \
             colour2 == "yellow", colour2 == "magenta", colour2 == "orange", \
             colour2 == "cyan"]):
        if colour2 == colour1:
            return False
        else:
            return True
    else:
        return False

def valid3(colour1, colour2, colour3):
    if any( [colour3 == "red", colour3 == "green", colour3 == "blue", \
             colour3 == "yellow", colour3 == "magenta", colour3 == "orange", \
             colour3 == "cyan"]):
        if any( [colour3 == colour2, colour3 == colour1]):
            return False
        else:
            return True
    else:
        return False

def valid4(colour1, colour2, colour3, colour4):
    if any( [colour4 == "red", colour4 == "green", colour4 == "blue", \
             colour4 == "yellow", colour4 == "magenta", colour4 == "orange", \
             colour4 == "cyan"]):
        if any( [colour4 == colour3, colour4 == colour2, colour4 == colour1]):
            return False
        else:
            return True
    else:
        return False

def drawGraphWin(width, height):
    win = GraphWin("CW PatchWork Deisgn", width*100, height*100)
    win.setCoords(0.0,0.0,4*width,3*height)
    for i in range(width):
        vLineN = Line(Point(i*4, 0), Point(i*4, height*3))
        vLineN.draw(win)
    for j in range(height):
        hLineN = Line(Point(0, j*3), Point(width*4, j*3))
        hLineN.draw(win)
    return win

def drawPattern(win, width, height, colour1, colour2, colour3, colour4):
    for widthNo in range(width):
        drawPatch1(win, widthNo, 0, colour1, colour2, colour3, colour4)
    for widthNo in range(width):
        drawPatch1(win, widthNo, height-1, colour1, colour2, colour3, colour4)
    for heightNo in range(height-2):
        drawPatch1(win, 0, heightNo+1, colour1, colour2, colour3, colour4)
    for heightNo in range(height-2):
        drawPatch1(win, width-1, heightNo+1, colour1, colour2, colour3, colour4)
    for innerNoH in range(width-2):
        innerWidth = innerNoH +1
    for innerNoV in range(height-2):
        innerHeight = height - 2 - innerNoV
            drawPatch2(win, innerWidth, innerHeight, colour1, colour2, colour3,\
                        colour4)
    win.getMouse()
    win.close()

def drawPatch1(win, widthNo, height, colour1, colour2, colour3, colour4):
    for i in range(6):
        vLineN = Line(Point((0.8*(i))+widthNo*4, 0+height*3), \
                      Point((0.8*(i))+widthNo*4, 3+height*3))
        vLineN.draw(win)
        hLineN = Line(Point(0+widthNo*4, (0.6*(i))+height*3), \
                      Point(4+widthNo*4, (0.6*(i))+height*3))
        hLineN.draw(win)
        if i == 0:
            for j in range(5):
                hiMessage = drawHiMessage(0.4+widthNo*4, (0.3+(j*0.6))+height*3,\
                                        win, colour1, colour2, colour3, colour4)
                hiMessage.setFill(colour1)
                vLineN.setFill(colour1)
                hLineN.setFill(colour1)
        elif i == 1:
            for k in range(5):
                hiMessage = drawHiMessage(1.2+widthNo*4, (0.3+(k*0.6))+height*3,\
                                        win, colour1, colour2, colour3, colour4)
                hiMessage.setFill(colour2)
                vLineN.setFill(colour2)
                hLineN.setFill(colour2)
        elif i == 2:
            for l in range(5):
                hiMessage = drawHiMessage(2+widthNo*4, (0.3+(l*0.6))+height*3, \
                                        win, colour1, colour2, colour3, colour4)
                hiMessage.setFill(colour3)
                vLineN.setFill(colour3)
                hLineN.setFill(colour3)
        elif i == 3:
            for m in range(5):
                hiMessage = drawHiMessage(2.8+widthNo*4, (0.3+(m*0.6))+height*3,\
                                        win, colour1, colour2, colour3, colour4)
                hiMessage.setFill(colour4)
                vLineN.setFill(colour4)
                hLineN.setFill(colour4)
        elif i == 4:
            for n in range(5):
                hiMessage = drawHiMessage(3.6+widthNo*4, (0.3+(n*0.6))+height*3,\
                                        win, colour1, colour2, colour3, colour4)
                hiMessage.setFill(colour1)
                vLineN.setFill(colour1)
                hLineN.setFill(colour1)

def drawHiMessage(x, y, win, colour1, colour2, colour3, colour4):
    hiMessage = Text(Point(x, y), "hi!")
    hiMessage.draw(win)
    hiMessage.setSize(7)
    return hiMessage

def drawPatch2(win, innerNoH, height, colour1, colour2, colour3, colour4):
    for i in range(4):
        x = (0.5+i)+innerNoH*4
        for j in range(3):
            y = (2.2-j)+height*3
            sail = drawBoat(x, y, win, colour1, colour2, colour3, colour4)
            if i == 0:
                sail.setFill(colour1)
            elif i == 1:
                sail.setFill(colour2)
            elif i ==2:
                sail.setFill(colour3)
            elif i == 3:
                sail.setFill(colour4)

def drawBoat(x, y, win, colour1, colour2, colour3, colour4):
    sail = Polygon(Point(x-0.5,y), Point(x,y+0.8), Point(x+0.5,y))
    hull = Polygon(Point(x-0.5,y-0.1), Point(x+0.5,y-0.1), Point(x+0.3,y-0.2), \
                   Point(x-0.3,y-0.2))
    mast = Line(Point(x,y), Point(x,y-0.1))
    sail.draw(win)
    hull.draw(win)
    mast.draw(win)
    hull.setFill("white")
    return sail

main()
```

Comment: it customary on SO to accept an answer (the tick mark under the up/down vote) that has solved your your issue. This marks the question as resolved and awards the person who the answer some points.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`itertools.cycle`](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/itertools.html?highlight=itertools#itertools.cycle) to go through all the colors repeatedly. So let's say that you have all your patches in a list called `patches`, you could do something like the following

```
import itertools
colors = ['red','blue','green','yellow']
patches = ['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j']

for patch, color in itertools.izip(patches, itertools.cycle(colors)):
    # color a patch
    print 'Colour', patch, 'as', color
```

prints out

```
Colour a as red
Colour b as blue
Colour c as green
Colour d as yellow
Colour e as red
Colour f as blue
Colour g as green
Colour h as yellow
Colour i as red
Colour j as blue
```

Comment: Thank you for the ideas so far. There pretty good, but if i used them i'd have to rewrite most of my code. I've now included my code in with the question. Is it pretty impossible to do what i need to do with that code? The colours it in at the moment, are my first attempts that went rather badly. Will i need to rewrite the code in you opinion?

Comment: @AlexJonBarry I've outlined a general approach in my original answer. Given the length of your code, I suggest you post a question of `codereview.stackexchange.com` as that is better suited for the purpose you are after (i.e. codereview).

Comment: Thanks for your help. I've managed to get it working using your original answer, just fairly repetitive when drawing the patches. Anyway, thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you do something like this:

```
for x in range(0,maxX-1):
   for y in range(0,maxY-1):
      paint_patch(x,y,color((x+y)%4)
```

Essentially what this will is start each row with a different color, cycling through them. You'll have nice diagonal lines as well.

Comment: Thank you for the ideas so far. There pretty good, but if i used them i'd have to rewrite most of my code. I've now included my code in with the question. Is it pretty impossible to do what i need to do with that code? The colours it in at the moment, are my first attempts that went rather badly. Will i need to rewrite the code in you opinion?

Comment: Looked through your code but without dissecting it, I can only assume you have a point at which you have a grid location, and you are putting a box there. At that point, figure out which color to use based off of the logic provided.

Comment: Yes i have a larger graphics window, dimensions defined by the user, prone to change, and each patch is a box that are equal dimensions to the others and fit within the graphics window. The problem i have is that because i have repeated the boxes, and the different patterns are governed by different codes, i cant create a universal code that changes the colour based on location, for any dimension given by the user